# how to select next or last elememt using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, swig-template

I am new to jQuery. I am clicking on a link which sends an ajax request and in the callback I want to change the text of the next `p` element.
My html code:

```
                <div> 
                 <img src="/images/{{comment.commenterPicName}}" class="img-circle">
                 <b>{{comment.commenterFirstName}}</b>
                 <p>{{comment.commentMessage}}</p>

                 {% if comment.isLiked %}
                    <a class="comment-like" id="{{comment.id}}">Unlike</a>
                 {% else %}
                    <a class="comment-like" id="{{comment.id}}">Like</a>
                 {% endif %}
                    <p>{{comment.likersCount}}</p>
                </div>
```

My jQuery Code:

```
$(".comment-like").click(function(e) {
var el =  $(this);
if ($(this).html() == "Like") {
    var parameters = { commentId: $(this).attr('id')};
    $.get(
        "/likeComment",
        parameters,
        function(data) { 
          el.parent().children('p').last().text(data);
        }
    );
    $(this).html('Unlike');
}
else {
    var parameters = { commentId: $(this).attr('id')};
    $.get(
        "/unlikeComment",
        parameters,
        function(data) { 
          el.parent().children('p').last().text(data);
        }
    );
    $(this).html('Like');
}
```

My problem is I can't change the `p` element containing likersCount. I tried `.next()` `.last()` etc. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is not pure HTML. Please add a tag at bottom of the question that identifies the additional library used *(angular.js, node.js, or whatever -- there is a tag for it. Just start typing it in)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have finally found the solution.

Instead of:

```
el.parent().children('p').last().text(data);
```

I had to use simply:

```
el.next('p').text(data);
```

This will invariably select the next `p` element which was precisely the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for the `.siblings()` selector. You can use it with other jQuery selectors to traverse your HTML.

This selector gets all elements at the same level of whatever element you call it from. You can find more information here. http://api.jquery.com/siblings/